# User button to select random Post and render with detail view

Tags: python, django, url, random, view

I've started using Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.3 to develop a website which will display customized "Posts", as in a blog Post.

I want the user to be able to click a button that basically says "Random Post". This button will take them to a template which loads a random blog post.

Here's my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ... other fields
    ... other fields

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here are some relevant views:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

Here is my problematic view:

```
import random

def random_post(request):
    post_ids = Post.objects.all().values_list('post_id', flat=True) 
    random_obj = Post.objects.get(post_id=random.choice(post_ids))
    context = {'random_post': random_obj,}
    return render(request, 'blog/random_post.html', context)
```

Here I am trying to create a Values List of all post_id values for the Post model. Then I'm trying to get a random choice from this Values List, which would be a random id. Then I'm trying to create a context and render a template using this logic.

Here are relevant urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('post/<int:pk>/', 
            views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
        path('post/random/<int:pk>', views.random_post, name='random_post'),
```

Needless to say this is not working.

If I leave off the , it renders a blank template with no data. If I include the , it causes an error - No Arguments Found. I assume that no data is being queried in the view, or the data isn't being properly sent from the view to the template.

I am new to Django. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the view that worked for me.

```
def random_post(request):
    post_count = Post.objects.all().count()  
    random_val = random.randint(0, post_count-1)  
    post_id = Post.objects.values_list('post_id', flat=True)[random_val]   
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_id) #Redirect to post detail view
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order all rows in the database with a unique key/ID then do the following to select a random database row:

```
maxnum = len(cursor.rowcount)
random.randint(1, maxnum)
```

Comment: This is useful for the 'random' part. How about the URLs and routing? How would I implement this?